# Fastest Python method for search and replace on a large string

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for the fastest way to replace a large number of sub-strings inside a very large string. Here are two examples I've used.

findall() feels simpler and more elegant, but it takes an astounding amount of time.

finditer() blazes through a large file, but I'm not sure this is the right way to do it.

Here's some sample code. Note that the actual text I'm interested in is a single string around 10MB in size, and there's a huge difference in these two methods.

```
import re

def findall_replace(text, reg, rep):
    for match in reg.findall(text):
        output = text.replace(match, rep)
    return output

def finditer_replace(text, reg, rep):
    cursor_pos = 0
    output = ''
    for match in reg.finditer(text):
        output += "".join([text[cursor_pos:match.start(1)], rep])
        cursor_pos = match.end(1)
    output += "".join([text[cursor_pos:]])
    return output

reg = re.compile(r'(dog)')
rep = 'cat'
text = 'dog cat dog cat dog cat'

finditer_replace(text, reg, rep)

findall_replace(text, reg, rep)
```

**UPDATE** Added re.sub method to tests:

```
def sub_replace(reg, rep, text):
    output = re.sub(reg, rep, text)
    return output
```

**Results**

re.sub() - 0:00:00.031000
finditer() - 0:00:00.109000
findall() - 0:01:17.260000

Comment: and the second one is really much faster? Seems strange to me, they should take approx. the same time. And i think both ways are correct.

Comment: why aren't you using re's sub method?

Comment: Using += with strings is an O(n^2) operation, compared to the O(n) of building a list and using "" to join.

Comment: Sören: yes, the difference between the two methods is profound.

Comment: Seth: I have no idea what that means

Comment: Is it a very simplified example? Because you could just use `the_string.replace('dog', 'cat')`. If it is, how complicated is the actual regex?

Comment: @cyrus You shouldn't write for match in reg.findall(text): because here match is not a match, it's a group in fact

Comment: Any idea how to scale this to do >20K substring replaces?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The standard method is to use the built-in

```
re.sub(reg, rep, text)
```

Incidentally the reason for the performance difference between your versions is that each replacement in your first version causes the entire string to be recopied.  Copies are fast, but when you're copying 10 MB at a go, enough copies will become slow.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't use re.sub() because I thought it operated in the same was as findall. I ran my tests again and re.sub is clearly the fastest method. The results have been added to the question.

Answer (score 6):

You can, and I think you must because it certainly is an optimized function, use

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count, flags])
```

The reason why your **findall_replace()** function is long is that at each match, a new string object is created, as you will see by executed the following code:

```
ch = '''qskfg qmohb561687ipuygvnjoihi2576871987uuiazpoieiohoihnoipoioh
opuihbavarfgvipauhbi277auhpuitchpanbiuhbvtaoi541987ujptoihbepoihvpoezi 
abtvar473727tta aat tvatbvatzeouithvbop772iezubiuvpzhbepuv454524522ueh'''

import re

def findall_replace(text, reg, rep):
    for match in reg.findall(text):
        text = text.replace(match, rep)
        print id(text)
    return text

pat = re.compile('\d+')
rep = 'AAAAAAA'

print id(ch)
print
print findall_replace(ch, pat, rep)
```

Note that in this code I replaced `output = text.replace(match, rep)` with `text = text.replace(match, rep)` , otherwise only the last occurence is replaced.

finditer_replace() is long for the same reason as for findall_replace(): repeated creation of a string object. But the former uses an iterator re.finditer() while the latter constructs beforhand a list object, so it is longer. That's the difference between iterator and not-iterator.

Answer (score 4):

By the way, your code with **findall_replace()** isn't safe, it can return unawaited results:

```
ch = 'sea sun ABC-ABC-DEF bling ranch micABC-DEF fish'

import re

def findall_replace(text, reg, rep):
    for gr in reg.findall(text):
        text = text.replace(gr, rep)
        print 'group==',gr
        print 'text==',text
    return '\nresult is : '+text

pat = re.compile('ABC-DE')
rep = 'DEFINITION'

print 'ch==',ch
print
print findall_replace(ch, pat, rep)
```

display

```
ch== sea sun ABC-ABC-DEF bling ranch micABC-DEF fish

group== ABC-DE
text== sea sun ABC-DEFINITIONF bling ranch micDEFINITIONF fish
group== ABC-DE
text== sea sun DEFINITIONFINITIONF bling ranch micDEFINITIONF fish

result is : sea sun DEFINITIONFINITIONF bling ranch micDEFINITIONF fish
```