# Python : compare two files with different line endings

Tags: python, compare, newline

I have two files. File `test.a` and `test.b`. `test.a` was pre-generated on unix machine. `test.b` is generated by user and can be generated both on windows and unix machines.

I can't use `filecmp.cmp('test01/test.a', 'test01/test.b')` because it'll always return false, all thanks to different line endings.

Is there any elegant solution to this? If not, what would be the best way to change line endings of unix file before comparing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the two are text files, using standard `open()` and `readline()` functions should work, because unless `b` is passed, they operate with universal newlines (converting to `\n`):

```
def cmp_lines(path_1, path_2):
    l1 = l2 = True
    with open(path_1, 'r') as f1, open(path_2, 'r') as f2:
        while l1 and l2:
            l1 = f1.readline()
            l2 = f2.readline()
            if l1 != l2:
                return False
    return True
```

That will compare the files line-by-line, and return `False` as soon as two non-matching lines are found (also closing the file, due to the `with` block). If all the lines match, it returns `True`. All newlines are automatically converted to `\n`. Note that `readline()` returns `''` when EOF (End Of File) is reached.

Answer (score 1):

What if you found what newline character the first line of one file used, and then depending on what that was, choose to replace all instances of that char with whatever the other file uses so you could use `cmp`, or not if they are already the same. I know you said you are dealing with large files, so perhaps this wouldn't suit at all.

However, look here regarding the detection of the newline character used in a file
[How can I detect DOS line breaks in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798627/how-can-i-detect-dos-line-breaks-in-a-file)

and here regarding efficiency in a search and replace on a large string
[Fastest Python method for search and replace on a large string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893506/fastest-python-method-for-search-and-replace-on-a-large-string)

hope this helps, apologies if not