# Is there a faster alternative to Python String.replace()

Tags: python, python-requests

I am writing a piece of code that requests a web page, parse it, and extracts certain information in it.

Everything works perfectly except for this part (**Edited**)

```
start_time = time.time()
r = requests.get(item_url)
print(time.time() - start_time)
formatted_html = r.text.replace('=\r\n', '')
print(time.time() - start_time)
formatted_html = re.sub('=\r\n', '', r.text)
print(time.time() - start_time)
```

**Output**

```
0.9731616973876953
1.9460444450378418
3.0275654792785645
```

The text.replace takes 1 seconds+ to complete and is used to fix a "quoted-printable" html string. There are also many web pages to cover (separated in threads), so I'm trying to speed up this "fix". I couldn't find a way to request the web page without being quoted-printable as well.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** It takes a lot of time because the string is huge (100k+ length)

**Edit:** I have tried re.sub, String.split() then join (None are significantly faster)

Comment: Are you sure that `.replace()` takes 1+ sec? You can type `print(r.elapsed)` to see how much time the actual request took.

Comment: You can use multithreading if the threads are not dependent on each other..

Comment: @HarrisonSeow Since you are parsing webpages that must involve HUGE amount of text, and the best solution for that is regex. Perhaps you might want to look in this question -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893506/fastest-python-method-for-search-and-replace-on-a-large-string

Comment: @IvanVinogradov I've added the way I measured the time for the function (with only 1 thread)

Comment: @RushabhSudame I thought threading is multithreading already, is there any difference? `t = threading.Thread(target=processMHT, kwargs=item)` is what I'm using

Comment: @Prince I've seen them and tried but they're basically the same, and I believe String.replace() is faster?

Comment: @HarrisonSeow you edited the question after comment..

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: @RushabhSudame It was always there (about threading), you can check the edit history.

Comment: @balderman Care to explain how to use it so that it's faster? I wasn't able to do it.

Comment: See https://lzone.de/examples/Python%20re.sub for examples

Comment: @balderman I've tried it the same as the example and there's no significant reduce